# Lebesgue integral question concerning orders of limit and integration

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, limits

I've got a hand-in question in a pure analysis course that I was hoping I might get a hint on - having difficulty coming up with a decent approach.

The question:

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a measurable function such that $$\int_X f(x)d\mu(x)=A,$$ for some $0<A<\infty$.
If $\alpha>0,$ show
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_X n\log\left(1 + \left(\frac{f(x)}{n}\right)^{\alpha} \right)d\mu(x)=\begin{cases}
\infty&\mbox{if }0<\alpha<1\\\
A&\mbox{if } \alpha=1\\\
0&\mbox{if }\alpha>1.
\end{cases}$$

My attempt at a solution only comes as far as the first part:

\begin{align*}
g(x,n)&=n\log(1 + [f(x)/n]^{\alpha})\\
&=n\cdot \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m+1}[f(x)/n]^{\alpha m}/m\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m+1}\cdot \frac{f(x)^{\alpha m}}{m\cdot n^{\alpha*m-1}} \\
&= \frac{f(x)^\alpha}{n^{\alpha-1}}+\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{m+1}\frac{f(x)^{\alpha m}}{m\cdot n^{\alpha m-1}},
\end{align*}
 which is increasing  in $n$ for $\alpha<1$ (this is a bit handwavy, but I can't seem to figure out how to show it in a strict manner). Thus, we can apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem to move the limit inside the integrand, transform $n=1/t$, use a bit of L'hopitals rule, and get that this limit is diverging for any $f(x)$ and $\alpha<1$ (and $f(x)$ for $\alpha=1$, zero for $\alpha>1$). But how do I go about proving that I can switch limit and integrand in these other cases, or is there any other simple way to prove it? Any hints would be much appreciated!

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Let $I_n(\alpha):=\int_X n\log\left(1+\left(\frac{f(x)}n\right)^{\alpha}\right)d\mu (x)$. If $0<\alpha<1$, since $\int_X fd\mu>0$ we can find $\beta>0$ such that $\mu(\{f\geq \beta\})>0$. Therefore we have 
\begin{align*}
I_n(\alpha)&\geq\mu(f\geq \beta)n\log\left(1+\left(\frac{\beta}n\right)^{\alpha}\right) \\
&\geq \mu(f\geq \beta)n\left(\left(\frac{\beta}n\right)^{\alpha}-\frac 12\left(\frac{\beta^2}{n^2}\right)^{\alpha}\right)\\
&=\mu(f\geq \beta)n^{1-\alpha}\left(\beta^{\alpha}-\frac{\beta^{2\alpha}}{2n^{\alpha}}\right)
\end{align*}
and it converges to $+\infty$.

If $\alpha=1$, the use of the inequality $x-\frac{x^2}2\leq \ln(1+x)\leq x$ allow us to apply the dominated convergence theorem.

If $\alpha>1$, use the measure $\nu=f\mu$ which is a probability measure. We have
$$I_n(\alpha)=\int_X\phi\left(\frac n{f(x)}\right)d\nu,$$
with $\phi(x)=x\ln (1+x^{-\alpha})$. Since $\phi'(x)=\ln(1+x^{-\alpha})-\alpha\frac{x^{-\alpha}}{1+x^{-\alpha}}$ and $\phi''(x)=\frac{-\alpha x^{-1-\alpha}}{1+x^{-\alpha}}-\frac 1{(1+x^{-\alpha})^2}(-\alpha x^{-\alpha-1})\alpha=-\alpha\frac{x^{-1-\alpha}}{1+x^{-\alpha}}x^{-\alpha}<0$ for $x>0$, $\phi$ is concave. Jensen's inequality yields
$$I_n(\alpha)=\int_X\phi\left(\frac n{f(x)}\right)d\nu\leq \phi\left(\int_X\frac n{f(x)}d\nu\right)\leq \left(\int_X\frac n{f(x)}d\nu\right)^{1-\alpha},$$
so it works if $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is finite. I guess we can solve the case $\sigma$-finite using the dominated convergence theorem for the counting measure.

Comment: The function $\phi = x\ln(1+x^{-\alpha})$ is not concave. You may plot the case where $\alpha = -2$, so there is probably something wrong in your differentiation.

Comment: I will check my differentiation. But why $\alpha=-2$? We assumed $\alpha>1$?